# Problema no tamanho do heap da JVM ao migrar do Solr 5.0 para o Solr 5,1

Tags: jvm, apache-solr

Tenho uma instância do Solr 5.0.0 em produção com a seguinte configuração de tamanho do heap da JVM:

```
SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
```

Quando migrei para o Solr 5.1.0 com a mesma configuração e iniciei o servidor, me deparei com o erro **OutOfMemoryError**. Ao observar a API do Solr percebi que o tamanho do heap estava com `512m`. Minha configuração de heap não está funcionando, fazendo com que o servidor seja iniciado com o tamanho de heap padrão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe um bug que ocorre apenas no Solr 5.1. Esse bug foi corrigido pelo time do Apache Solr e está na versão 5.2 do Solr.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7454

O problema é que o Solr 5.1 não usa mais a variável `SOLR_JAVA_MEM` para alterar o tamanho do heap da JVM. Nessa versão usa-se a variável `SOLR_HEAP` que altera o heap mínimo e máximo com o mesmo valor:

```
SOLR_HEAP="2g"
```

Dessa maneira o Solr será iniciado com `-Xms=2g` e `-Xmx=2g`

No Solr 5.2 esse problema foi corrigido e as duas variáveis `SOLR_JAVA_MEM` e `SOLR_HEAP` funcionam corretamente.